# How do I prove that this function is Riemann Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

$f(x)=1/(x+3)$ over the interval [0,1]

Here the function is a monotone function. So it is Riemann integrable. But is there a way I could prove that the given function is Riemann Integrable. I tried solving the problem by using partitions but I could not prove it.

Comment: Integration, maybe? $\int \frac{dx}{x+3}=\ln|x+3|+C$.

Comment: A continuous function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: I want to show it is Riemann Integrable. I don't want the value of it through integration. @MichaelGaluza

Comment: Do you want evaluate Riemann sum? And do not use any other results or theorems?

Comment: Yes I know that, but is there a way I can prove that the given function is Riemann Integrable by taking partitions and all of that? @Gary.

Comment: It's pretty much equally easy to prove that an arbitrary continuous function is Riemann integrable as it is to prove that a specific continuous function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Yes I know how to prove that an arbitrary continuous function is Riemann integrable. But I was just wondering whether it is possible to prove Riemann Integrability for the specific function through upper sums and lower sums.@Ian

Comment: Then bound $U(\pi)-L(\pi)$ by the maximum of $f(x)-f(y)$ for $(x,y)$ in a same interval of the partition $\pi$ (times $1$ the length of $[0,1]$). Since $f(x)-f(y)=(y-x)/((3+x)(3+y))$, $|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant|y-x|/9$ for every $(x,y)$ hence $U(\pi)-L(\pi)\leqslant m(\pi)/9$ where $m(\pi)$ is the mesh of the partition $\pi$. QED

Comment: @Did, maybe you should convert it into answer?

Answer (score 2):

Even easier: the integrand function is a Lipschitz function, hence for every partition of $[0,1]$ the difference between the upper sum and the lower sum is bounded by the Lipschitz constant $L$ times the width of the largest interval of the partition. Riemann integrability readily follows.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

**Claim:** A continuous function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is Riemann integrable.

**Proof:** Given $\varepsilon > 0$ since $f$ is continuous in a compact, it is also uniformly continuous at $[a,b]$, then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x,y \in [a,b]$, $$|y - x| < \delta \implies |f(y) - f(x)|  < \frac{\varepsilon}{b-a}$$

Take a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ on which every interval ahas length $< \delta$. For every interval $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$ there exists $x_i,y_i$ such that $m_i = f(x_i)$ and $M= f(y_i)$, then $\omega = f(y_i) - f(x_i) < \frac{\varepsilon}{b-a}$. It follows that $$\sum \omega_i (t_i - t_{i-1}) < \varepsilon$$

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. But I don't want to use the result you are talking about. I want to prove it by using Riemann criterion for Integrability.

Comment: Follow the proof, and you have what you're looking for.

Comment: @AbhishekBhat: Do you mean using Lower- and Upper sums?

Comment: Yes, the function is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Yes. I just want to know whether it is possible through lower and upper sums @Gary.

Comment: Unless you got a different definition for oscilation, I can't understand your reasoning. $$U(f;P) - L(f;) = \sum \omega_i (t_i - t_{i-1})$$

Comment: In the proof he did it with lower and upper sums if he means by $m_i$ and $M_i$ the minimum/maximum in each interval. Then his final sum is precisly "upper sum - lower sum", which gets arbitrary small, which is one criterion for Riemann-integrability.

Comment: Guess your first selection of $\delta > 0$ should be for $\varepsilon / (b-a)$ for your proof to work, not just $\varepsilon$...

Comment: @Stefan You're right!

Comment: @AbhishekBhat: I wrote an answer that goes together with Aarons, using upper - and lower- sums.

Comment: I completely agree what you are saying and even your proof is correct. But I want you to take the very function that I have given and prove Riemann Integrability for that particular function by taking some partition. I just want to know whether it is possible or not? @AaronMaroja

Comment: Lower and upper sums are defining the Darboux integral that is the same that the Riemann integral. The definitions of Darboux and Riemann are different but they are the same integral. The sums are not a "proof": they are the definition of the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of generalizing/extending what Aaron said, basically rewording it, since redundancy can help: You want to have upper- and lower sums so that , for any $\epsilon>0$, $U-L <\epsilon$.

As pointed out by Aaron, a continuous function in a(n) (compact) interval $[x_k, x_{k+1}]$ $f(x)$ takes maximum and minimum values $M,m$ on the interval. Now, you want to use these $M,m$  for your upper- and lower- sums. For this you need to make $M-m$ as small as you want. Can you see that making the intervals $[x_k, x_{k+1}]$ smaller, using uniform continuity can help you do that?